# How to create a unique array of users?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have such entity.

**entity:**

```
@Entity('rooms')
export class Room {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => User)
  @JoinTable()
  users: User[];
}
```

Let's say I added three users to the first room:

**Room 1:**

```
[
  {
    "roomId": "813208f5-7a0d-4fbe-a4e2-b090fab92745",
    "userId": "a4aca468-c713-4cb8-9646-fd2667f88bfc"
  },
  {
    "roomId": "813208f5-7a0d-4fbe-a4e2-b090fab92745",
    "userId": "f0544438-df2e-491d-ac4c-105f33346055"
  },
  {
    "roomId": "813208f5-7a0d-4fbe-a4e2-b090fab92745",
    "userId": "c4072255-84b3-4714-96b5-8c5d7874a5c4"
  },
]
```

And if I try to create a second room with the same users I should get a uniqueness error:

**Room 2 FALSE:**

```
[
  {
    "roomId": "c7f646e4-402d-42ab-8b87-1b13228e764a",
    "userId": "a4aca468-c713-4cb8-9646-fd2667f88bfc"
  },
  {
    "roomId": "c7f646e4-402d-42ab-8b87-1b13228e764a",
    "userId": "f0544438-df2e-491d-ac4c-105f33346055"
  },
  {
    "roomId": "c7f646e4-402d-42ab-8b87-1b13228e764a",
    "userId": "c4072255-84b3-4714-96b5-8c5d7874a5c4"
  },
]
```

But if the new room will consist of at least one new user, then the room must be created:

**Room 2 TRUE:**

```
[
  {
    "roomId": "c7f646e4-402d-42ab-8b87-1b13228e764a",
    "userId": "5aea13a9-03e5-4b46-9cec-35da3d77a81f"
  },
  {
    "roomId": "c7f646e4-402d-42ab-8b87-1b13228e764a",
    "userId": "f0544438-df2e-491d-ac4c-105f33346055"
  },
  {
    "roomId": "c7f646e4-402d-42ab-8b87-1b13228e764a",
    "userId": "c4072255-84b3-4714-96b5-8c5d7874a5c4"
  },
]
```

How can such a condition be specified?

Comment: Will you always have 3 users per room? Should you detect if 4 users are the same? If you have a room with user 1, 2, 3, 4, and you attempt to create a room with 1, 2, 3 is that valid? What if you have 1, 2, 3, and you try to create 1, 2, 3, 4 is that valid?

Comment: @kevintechie There will always be three users

Comment: Can you create a small demo project with this issue? Because now it is not clear why this is happening...